# Controling Data stream using C# windows service app

Tags: c#, database, url, streaming, ping

i've 15 urls, and i want to Ping or stm like that so that i could check the speed of all URL's and TTL , and switch and stream data from the fastest server, anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The server with the best ping and TTL time doesn't necessarily will give you the best stream result

Comment: hmm ok, I guess you're right, it's just that i don't have any idea in this topic, i'm new in c# and moreover i've never written anything like this before, so how should do it???

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned in the headline you need some kind of thread (or service) which is checking constantly. A windows service can be made within Visual Studio including a proper installer. I would than use a shared ressource like a file or a database to populate the fastest url to it. Maybe you can also use some kind of population through a Remote Object by the service and an Application Server. I would think you develop the service and the client for the urls with the same domain project to share the Access to the ressource between projects. Within the windows service you can trigger the test of the url's by a timeout in the thread and so on...

After that you can access the shared ressource with your client to fetch the fastest connection in a certain moment. If you need more informatin about Remote Objects or a Windows Service please have a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/remoteobject1.aspx

http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=31

http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service

Comment: I've already written and service which check all urls from a stream file, and writes down the one which give response and the one which doesn't in different stream file, but i want to get the one the highest data in/out speed... but i have no one how to do that/

Comment: Oh i see. You have to create workload by streaming test files from the urls. maybe you do that by switching the streaming between the urls every few seconds for some time. But be careful! If there is now workload balancer on the url's you can drop the overall performance for the rest of the users. Then you build a statistic for the down rate over a time window that a streaming usually last. You choose the url which is on rank 1 of this statistic.

Comment: i've already had that problem, so right now i try to get the one with highest speed, can i use ping class somehow to accomplish this?

Comment: No not really. Because Streaming has nothing to do with reaction times. You rely on the overall network and server performance. Without Load Balancing and Load testing it is really just a game of luck. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/vstswebtest/threads might help.

Comment: well thank's i'll try to use Load testing & Load testing , i just have to learn a little bit more bout them, i have no idea what are they, but thank you very much, :)

Comment: Maybe you just record a performance statistic over time while just using random urls and switch between urls with an automaton model regarding the test statistic. wether to switch randomly or on some purpose should rely on the statistics. So combine testing and streaming and "learn" the best practice url from the overall usage